# How to specify the path to a file on a Windows CE device?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, windows-ce, filepath, windows-embedded-compact

I copied over some code from a test app:

```
const string sdfPath = @"C:\WebAPIClient\WebAPIClient\bin\Debug\DBPlatypusCompactDB.sdf";
string dataSource = string.Format("Data Source={0}", sdfPath);
int countAdded = 0;

    if (!File.Exists(sdfPath))
. . .
```

...which works fine there; but on trying to convert it for use in the project that will run on the Windows CE device:

```
const string sdfPath = @"Computer\WindowsCE\\\Program Files\hhs\DBPlatypusCompactDB.sdf";            
. . .
```

...(this is the path I copied from Windows Explorer (the folder to which the exe is deployed, which has no subfolders)), I get "path not found" or "path not valid" or something similar.

How am I to designate the path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, so here are some general pointers:

1. Windows CE doesn't understand relative paths.  Period.  So all paths must start with a backslash (`\`) character.
2. "Computer" is highly unlikely to be part of the path on your device.  Use Explorer on the device ansd look at the path there.  What you're after is probably something like `\Program Files\hhs\mydatabase.sdf`
3. Desktop paths to a device are not actual paths.  They are shell plug-in trickery.  A path on the PC like `My Device\Program Files\foo.bar` is not a path resolvable by any File APIs on the desktop.  If you want to access a device file from a PC app, you must use something like RAPI to pull the file locally, then use the local copy

Comment: "Computer" *is* what Windows Explorer on the desktop said, but from the device itself, it was "\\Program Files\\hhs\DBPlatypus.sdf" and that works fine; thanks!

Comment: Windows CE doesn't understand relative paths because there is no notion of "Current Directory for a Process" in Windows CE.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to run on device use this code:

**const string sdfPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase + @"\FolderName\Filename.*"**

but, you need to copy **FolderName** to device on **Program File** path see images folder example:

[Connect to your device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDRX4.png)

[Show images folder example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jySzQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.